# What is a good book about natural numbers from the set theoretical point of view?

Tags: number-theory, set-theory, book-recommendation, natural-numbers

I am not looking for a general set theory book, but rather something like a number theory book, but rooted in set theory.

E.g. the starting point might be the order theory, then well ordering, then it might introduce von Neumann natural numbers, then some properties of such a set are proven, e.g. different induction theorems and then it goes into more advanced stuff, especially stuff that requires set theory (like for example (but not necessarily) the Goodstein theorem).

Do you know about any book like that?